# Ubuntu 18.04 64bit and 32bit on same HDD with legacy BIOS

Tags: 18.04, grub2, 64-bit, 32-bit

Not able to install Ubuntu 18.04 64bit and 18.04 32bit on the same HDD with legacy BIOS. After installing 64bit both are not working and the desktop booting to grub> prompt with ls command giving incompatible file system error. But this 64 bit can be run from USB disk boot menu. The 32bit not running either from HDD boot menu or from USB disk boot menu

[The ls output at grub and root output shows swap partition as root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkxB4.jpg)

Comment: Most 32-bit software can be run on a 64-bit installation.  What is the **actual** problem that you face?  Perhaps you should ask about that instead of asking how to implement a solution that is messy, at best.  Worst case, it doesn't help at all.  Don't fall into this trap: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: You can install x86 & x86_64 on the same machine without issues, I've done it in QA testing only recently with the latest 18.04.5 ISO (done in both orders too actually this cycle with *flavors*). Your error seems to be that you either did something wrong (the /boot/grub/ cannot be read by MBR thus stuck at grub rescue accidently being overwritten), or corruption occurred thus requiring you to run `fsck` which will allow the the /boot/grub/ (of the version owning MBR) to be executed first. I can't follow your actual problem from what you've given though.

Comment: @guiverc my desktop was running on ubuntu18.04 32bit but when I found that my machine can support 64bit I resized the 32bit partition and installed 64bit version. After boot it is stuck on grub> prompt and giving error for ls command. I did fsck it did some long name short job but still stuck at grub>

Comment: @guiverc pls see the screen shot showing ls and root output at grub. Not understood how the swap partition is showing as root.

Comment: There maybe complexities because some older hardware has 32-bit BIOS/UEFI, which puts limits on x86_64/*amd64* installs; as most my hardware is enterprise grade (not consumer grade) I've had little experience with that so can't advise.  From your screen I'd boot a *live* system & check your file-systems (`fsck`) to ensure partitions are as expected. If any errors are detected & fixed, it may boot next time normally (with luck).

Comment: @guiverc The funny thing is from this desktop on my removable hard disk I have installed 18.04 64bit,18.04 32bit, 12.04 32bit side by side and working fine. Only on the HDD of desktop it is giving error. The only difference is the HDD of desktop have Windows 10 besides Ubuntu and on removable disk there is Windows Vista besides various Ubuntu installations.